# Ansible update value with pipeline parameter

Tags: ansible

I run Ansible from Azure devops pipeline. I want to update hosts value with parameter which is selected by user as a parameter(virtualmachine1, virtualmachine2 ...) during trigger azure devops pipeline

The existing configuration is :

```yaml
- hosts: tag_vm__virtualmachine1
```

I tried this one

```yaml
- hosts: tag_vm__"${{ parameters.vmname}}"
```

but fails with error below:

> We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
> missing quotes. Always quote template expression brackets when they
> start a value. For instance:
>
> ```
> with_items:
>   - {{ foo }}
> ```
>
> Should be written as:
>
> ```
> with_items:
>   - "{{ foo }}"
> ```

Any idea about the fix?

Comment: "_I run Ansible from Azure DevOps pipeline._", how do you do this? Can you provide the command or the relevant script snippet which is used in order to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `vmname` has to be declared.

```yaml
- hosts: "tag_vm__{{ vmname }}"
  vars:
    vmname:
  tasks:
    - name: "simple condition"
      debug:
        msg: "{{ ansible_host }}"
```

If you run it you will obtain

```bash
ansible-playbook --extra-vars "vmname=virtualmachine1" test.yml

# PLAY [tag_vm__virtualmachine1]
# ********************************
```

However, the `hosts` the playbook is intended to indicate on **which hosts or group of hosts a playbook can be run against** (in your case say a group named `all_vms`). Then, if you want to limit the play to a host (or a group of hosts), use the built-in `--limit` flag as described in [the documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory_guide/intro_patterns.html).

```bash
ansible-playbook --limit tag_vm__virtualmachine1 test.yml
```